# What is an Ancestor Method?

Tags: controller, visualforce-component, custom-controller, method

I have a leadConvertController that is tied to several components and other controllers. One line keeps giving me a Method does not override an ancestor method. I don't even know where to start to fix it because I have no idea what an ancestor method is. Could someone shed some light on what that error could mean. Excuse my ignorance, I'm new to development.

Comment: can you post your code, looks like you are using override keyword incorrectly in your code ?

Comment: @rao Let me add it to the question if I can.